# KineticJS dragBoundFunc not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've got this calling function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#change-background').click(function(){
         layers['map'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
         buildMap(layers['map'],'img/test.png');
         stage.add(layers['map']);
       });
    });
```

And, I've got this function to display the image

```
    function buildMap(layer, img_src){
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = img_src;
      img.onload = function(e) {
        var map = new Kinetic.Image({
          id: 'map_img',
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: img,
          draggable: true,
          dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
            // THIS SHOULD EXECUTE
            console.log('hahaha');
            return { x:0, y:0 };
          }
        });
        layer.add(map);
        layer.draw();
      };
    }
```

I have a similar code on a separate project of mine, and it works like a charm.. But its quite awkward that it does not work well here. The image showed up in the canvas, and its **draggable**, which in this case it should not be because I explicitly returned `{ x:0, y:0 }`**(the return values is for my testing only)**. I also looked at the console logs the **'hahaha'** text never appears.. It did not call the function when the image has been dragged. Both of these are inside a `<script>` tags and in one html document.

Comment: I just saw the error causing the problem.. I've been using kinetic-v3.10.0 for this project.. I think this version 3.10.0 have some issues with the dragBoundFunc.. I tried importing the 4.2.0 but error will display on my console..

Comment: jsfiddle link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sldhagz/YTUp6/2/)

Comment: have you considered using a newer version of kineticjs? like 4.3?

Comment: <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have just tried it.. and yes.. my dragBoundFunc worked.. but my 'Add New Polygon' doesn't.. the console will be me the message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined ` and if i'll collapse it there would be a `(anonymous function)` written.

Comment: You have to rewrite your add polygon function to meet the new configurations in the new kineticJS.

Comment: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-polygon-tutorial/

Comment: I have only pulled the implementation of the polygons [here](http://tech.joshuacummings.com/2012/07/scalable-draggable-anchored-triangle-in.html).. do you have any other recommendations for new implementations? I would really be helpful. Thanks. :)

Comment: You'll also have to redefine your anchors

Comment: yeah.. i think that would also be the case.. this implementation is what i have followed, is this outdated? [http://tech.joshuacummings.com/2012/07/scalable-draggable-anchored-triangle-in.html](http://tech.joshuacummings.com/2012/07/scalable-draggable-anchored-triangle-in.html) do you have links for an updated one? :)

Comment: This is not perfect, but gets you pretty close http://jsfiddle.net/jdA3y/

Comment: my goal for the polygons is to create custom shapes.. with unlimited number of anchors.. :D it worked in 3.10.. i'll try my best to learn from the example you gave.. Thanks again.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this:  http://jsfiddle.net/xpLPT/2/

try :

```
 dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
      console.log('hahaha');  //check the jsfiddle, this does work.
      return {
        x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,  //constrain vertically
        y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y   //constrain horizontally
      }
 }
```

also change your click function by adding stage.draw();:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#change-background').click(function(){
     //if(layers['map'])
          // layers['map'].remove(); // this is optional, but recommended, as it removes the current map layer before adding a new one
     layers['map'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
     buildMap(layers['map'],'img/test.png');
     stage.add(layers['map']);
     stage.draw();
   });
});
```

try using a newer version of kinetics:

```
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xpLPT/3/ , an update, if you look at this it does fire correctly. And as a performance issue, everytime you do a click on the '#change-background' button you're adding a new layer, shouldn't do that.

Comment: a newer version of kinetics is out and it fixed issues of the drag bounds function.

Comment: it works like a charm! :D
i have added the `layers['map'].remove();` but the console will give me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function map() { [native code] } has no method 'remove'` I think this is caused by jQuery..

Comment: Not JQuery, the problem is that the first time the function is executed, the object doesn't exist but it is trying to be removed. Let me edit it and try it as above.